# Using Either correctly

Tags: haskell

So I have the following function:

```
chk2 :: [(Integer,Integer)] -> Either [(Integer,Integer)] (Integer,Integer)
chk2 i@((n,_):_)
  | chkp (prod $ lgst i)==True = Right $ lgst i
  | lgst i==i!!0 = Left $ chk2 $ (4-2,4-2):next i                                           
  | otherwise = Left $ chk2 $ next i
  where prod (a,b) = a*b
        lgst = foldl1 (\(a,b) (c,d) -> if prod (a,b) > prod (c,d) then (a,b) else (c,d))
        next t = map (\(a,b) -> if (a,b)==lgst t then (a-1,b+1) else (a,b)) t
```

along with this error:

```
runhugs: Error occurred
ERROR "4/4.hs":14 - Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : chk2
*** Type           : [(Integer,Integer)] -> Either (Either [(Integer,Integer (Integer,Integer)) (Integer,Integer)
*** Does not match : [(Integer,Integer)] -> Either [(Integer,Integer)] (Integer,Integer)
```

I'm trying to get this function to either end up with an **(a,b)** i.e. first guard or **[(a,b)]** i.e. the latter two guards. The basic problem is in the latter two guards.. if I take out the recursion, everything works fine, but I'm not sure how to define the type signature when returning the function itself.

Comment: Pastebins make for bad questions. questions should be self contained to remain useful into the future.

Comment: Was just about to say the same as awoodland. Pasted the code for you this time.

Comment: @Chris Bolton: what are you trying to solve here?

Comment: porting my lua version of euler #4: https://github.com/saiko-chriskun/Project-Euler/blob/master/4.lua

Comment: I don't get what `lgst` does, but it returns a pair and you're comparing it to a list.

Comment: lgst takes a list of tuples and returns the one with the largest product. anyways I don't think anything is wrong with lgst, as it all works fine when I take out the recursion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with how you recurse.

According to the type of `chk2`, `chk2 $ next i` is of type `Either [(Integer,Integer)] (Integer,Integer)`.  `Left` is of type `b -> Either b a`, so  `Left $ chk2 $ next i` is of type `Either (Either [(Integer,Integer)] (Integer,Integer)) a` for some unspecified type `a`.

`Left $ chk2 $ (4-2,4-2):next i` has a similar problem.

To fix, you need to decide how you want to handle the recursive value.

Easy fix:

```
  | lgst i==i!!0 = chk2 $ (4-2,4-2):next i                                           
  | otherwise = chk2 $ next i
```

However, I doubt this is what you want, since it means all your results will be `Right`.
I'm not sure how to do what you want, because I'm not sure what you want.

What does a list result mean?  What does a non-list result mean?

What you probably want to do is pattern match the result of the recursion, transforming `Right pair -> Left [pair]`, perhaps appending some other result to the front.

As an example, I'll construct a recursive function with a similar type signature.  Let `foo` be a function that takes a list of integers, and:

- if the first element of the list is the maximum of the whole list, returns that element
- otherwise, return a subsequence of the list, where each is the maximum of all the elements between it and the next element in the subsequence (or the end)

To do this:

```
foo :: [Integer] -> Either [Integer] Integer
foo [] = Left []
foo (x:xs) = case foo xs of
  Left ys -> if all (<=x) ys
              then Right x
              else let (_,ys') = break (>x) ys in Left (x:ys')
  Right y -> if x >= y
              then Right x
              else Left [x,y]
```

Note how I use `case` to pattern match on the result of the recursive call to `foo`.

Comment: I tried chk2 :: [(Integer,Integer)] -> Either (Either [(Integer,Integer)] (Integer,Integer)) (Integer,Integer) but just makes the error more complicated.

Comment: Edited to include some fixes.

Comment: Changing the type won't help.  If your function is of type `a -> Either b c`, then the recursive call will return something of type `Either b c`, and wrapping it with `Left` means that it returns something of `Either (Either b c) d`, which contradicts the original type assertion.

Comment: @Chris Bolton: Edited to add some advice on how to fix.

Answer (score 1):

To solve Euler #4, yours seems to be a very awkward style for Haskell. It's usually a bad idea to try and "port" code from other languages into Haskell, since the paradigm for Haskell is so very different.

You'll find a very clean, sensible solution to Euler #4 that uses list comprehensions [at the Haskell Wiki](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Euler_problems/1_to_10#Problem_4). Certainly not the only solution, but it is at least 20x as readable as your current code. No offense.

I (and tons of other Haskellers) highly recommend [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com) and [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/) for learning how to approach problems the Haskell way, which in my experience is usually to create small, simple helper methods and compose them into a solution.